# Normalizing a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Given an array, I want to normalize it such that each row sums to 1.

I currently have the following code:

```
import numpy
w = numpy.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
                 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
                 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
                 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
                 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]], dtype = float)


def rownormalize(array):
    i = 0
    for row in array:
        array[i,:] = array[i,:]/sum(row)
        i += 1
```

I've two questions:

1) The code works, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way.

2) How can I convert the data type into a float if it's int? I tried

```
if array.dtype == int:
    array.dtype = float
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do 1) like that:

```
array /= array.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

and 2) like that:

```
array = array.astype(float)
```

Comment: If I add "    if array.dtype == int:    array.astype(float)" to the start of my function, it gives me a matrix of zeros (except one element which is 1)

Comment: That works if I add `return array` and change my code to `w = rownormalize(w)` instead of `rownormalize(w)`. Is there any way I can do it without making the above changes? If you're not sure, its fine

Comment: If you had only 1) it would work, but with type conversion I think you cannot. So halfway solution could be to do 1) inplace, and just do 2) before calling 1)

Comment: @wwl Julien Bernu's post+comments answered both of your queries, so I think it would be fair to accept his post, if it answered both of those sufficiently.

Answer (score 4):

Divisions even though `broadcasted` across all elements could be expensive. An alternative with focus on performance, would be to pre-compute the reciprocal of row-summations and use those to perform `broadcasted` multiplications instead, like so -

```
w *= 1.0/w.sum(1,keepdims=1)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [588]: w = np.random.rand(3000,3000)

In [589]: out1 = w/w.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) #@Julien Bernu's soln

In [590]: out2 = w*(1.0/w.sum(1,keepdims=1))

In [591]: np.allclose(out1,out2)
Out[591]: True

In [592]: %timeit w/w.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) #@Julien Bernu's soln
10 loops, best of 3: 66.7 ms per loop

In [593]: %timeit w*(1.0/w.sum(1,keepdims=1))
10 loops, best of 3: 40 ms per loop
```

Comment: The difference is not huge but since it is so easily done I will try to remember this trick!

Comment: @JulienBernu Yup! Specially with `broadcasting`, this comes in handy!

Comment: BTW, *why* is it any faster? There is a division in both cases and yours also does a multiplication... I assume `1/x` must be much faster than `y/x` but why is that, and if that's the case then why isn't `y/x` automatically computed as `y*(1/x)` all the time?